Not working Mobile view and Desktop view properly when we searched on website
As we were working on WordPress the problem arose when it did not accept mobile view and desktop view properly
Even it was published to check whether it is working or not
please tell us how to rectify...

Would you be able to provide more details? The issue is unclear.
